# How to fetch properties from config-server consisting of more than one repo

Tags: spring-boot, cloud-foundry, spring-config

I wanted to fetch properties from two git repos. one is https://username@bitbucket.my.domain.com/share.git - which will have a property file contains some common key value pair and the other one is https://username@bitbucket.my.domain.com/service.git - it will have property files of all the micro services. 
While I am deploying the service only one yml file (which is in https://username@bitbucket.my.domain.com/share.git repo) is read by the config server. What I am missing? How to read the property file from another repo i.e. https://username@bitbucket.my.domain.com/service.git too?

I wanted to deploy the service in PCF. So I configured the config-server in PCF with the following json.

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "git": {
        "label": "feature",
        "uri": "https://username@bitbucket.my.domain.com/share.git",
        "username": "username",
        "password": "password",
        "repos": {
            "configserver": {
                "password": "password",
                "label": "feature",
                "uri": "https://username@bitbucket.my.domain.com/service.git"
                "username": "username"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Name of my service is *LogDemo* and spring profile is *active*. I have created two yml files and placed in the corresponding repo. (I have given same name two both the files like *LogDemo-active.yml*). While I am deploying the service only one yml file (which is in https://username@bitbucket.my.domain.com/share.git repo) is read by the config server. */env* is giving me the following:

```
{
  "profiles": [
    "active",
    "cloud"
  ],
  "server.ports": {
    "local.server.port": 8080
  },
  "configService:configClient": {
    "config.client.version": "234e59d4a9f80f035f00fdf07e6f9f16e5560a55"
  },
  "configService:https://username@bitbucket.my.domain.com/share.git/LogDemo-active.yml": {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2"
  },
  ...................
  ...................
```

**What I am missing? How to read the property file from other repo i.e. https://username@bitbucket.my.domain.com/service.git too?**

Below is my bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: LogDemo
  mvc:
    view:
      prefix: /
      suffix: .jsp
```

Here is my manifest file

```
---
inherit: baseManifest.yml
applications:
- name: LogDemo
  host: LogDemo
  env:
    LOG_LEVEL: INFO
    spring.profiles.active: active
    TZ: America/New_York
  memory: 1024M
  domain: my.domain.com
  services:
  - config-server-comp
```

Comment: It looks like it may be a pattern matching issue. Your `spring.application.name` is `LogDemo`, but the config server repo that's not being used has a name of `configserver`. That means the pattern to indicate this repo should be used is `configserver/*`. I think it would work if you renamed this to `LogDemo`, or renamed your app to `configserver`. See https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/single/spring-cloud-config.html#_pattern_matching_and_multiple_repositories. If you don't want to deal with this, I think you could use a composite backend with two Git repos.

Comment: @DanielMikusa Yes. You are right. it's a matching issue.I renamed the tag from 'configserer' to 'LogDemo' and it worked. In fact, if i add a field like "pattern": "LogDemo/active then also it worked". But  in both the cases then, properties from https://username@bitbucket.my.domain.com/share.git or first URI is not being read.

Comment: Thanks @DanielMikusa. It worked perfectly with composite backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using multiple repos, the repos that will be applied depend on the pattern's defined for those repos. The default pattern is `<repo-name>/*`. Thus changing the repo name to `LogDemo` will activate the repo for your app, because the app name, `spring.application.name`, is `LogDemo`.

If one or more patterns match, then the repo for the matched patterns will be used. If no pattern matches then the default is used.

Full details are described in the docs here.

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/single/spring-cloud-config.html#_pattern_matching_and_multiple_repositories

If you don't need or want the pattern matching feature, you can use the [composite backend](
https://docs.pivotal.io/spring-cloud-services/2-0/common/config-server/composite-backends.html). The composite backend allows you to define multiple Git repositories. See the first config example here.

https://docs.pivotal.io/spring-cloud-services/2-0/common/config-server/composite-backends.html#general-configuration